# Using react-router-dom's Redirect with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been following the documentation here from react-router-dom's [Redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md). Right now, I have a component like that renders the following:

```
return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { previousPath: path } }} />;
```

However, I'm not sure how to access `previousPath` in state at my new path. The documentation is not clear on this. How do I access `previousPath`?

Answer (score 1):

One of your parent components should be `Route` with props: match, location, history. You should be able to use the state you created with `props.location.state` to access your `previousPath` value.

See [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) in the React Router docs.

Comment: Thanks Julian. I'm able to get to set `previousPath` to the correct value... however, I'm wondering how I access `previousPath` in another component? i.e. the component that's rendered from the Redirect

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using `ownProps` in [mapStateToProps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md):

In my `Login` component (where the Redirect goes), I added this to my `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    ...
    previousPath: ownProps.location.state.previousPath,
});
```

And then in my props, now I have access to `previousPath`.

Comment: mapStateToProps is from redux :P, if you look at my updated answer you will see I beat you to the punch by over half an hour

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md:

```
    <Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    search: "?utm=your+face",
    state: { referrer: currentLocation }
  }}
/>
```